# Mongoose + node.js findOne(), find() not giving results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have taken up learning node.js a few days back and i am facing some problem while retrieving data.

I am using mongoose in node.js and save() function is working but when i try to retrieve data using find() or findOne() my page keeps loading for a long time and does not give any result.

**models/chatrooms.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var tblchatroomsSchema = new Schema({
    chatusers: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'tblchatrooms' },
    chatroomid: {type: Number, required: true, index: { unique: true }},        // Every chat has 1 room id
    totalmember: Number,    // Indicates total number of members
    status: Number,         // 0 = closed, 1 = Open
    created: Date,
    chatlog: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('tblchatrooms', tblchatroomsSchema);
```

**routes.js**

```
>     var tblchatrooms = require('./models/tblchatrooms');
>     ......
>     ......
>     
>         app.get('/member', function (req, res) {
>             
>             //res.send("Hello World");
>             //exit;
>             if(!req.session.userid){
>                 res.send('Please login to chat with verified Membmers.');
>             }
>     
>              tblchatrooms.findOne({totalmember: 1, status: 1}), function(err, c) {
>                 if(err){
>                     res.send(err);
>                 } else {
>                     console.log(c);
>                     res.send(c);
>                 };
>             };


});
```

I am passing 2 condition to find a single record.

Document that i have in collection

**tblchatrooms**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546c9a6685ff7dc00d7d3b72"),
    "chatusers" : ObjectId("546c58c2fe985f480c008055"),
    "chatroomid" : 517048,
    "totalmember" : 1,
    "status" : 1,
    "created" : ISODate("2014-11-19T13:25:58.410Z"),
    "chatlog" : "empty",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546c9a7f85ff7dc00d7d3b73"),
    "chatusers" : ObjectId("546c58c2fe985f480c008055"),
    "chatroomid" : 894109,
    "totalmember" : 1,
    "status" : 1,
    "created" : ISODate("2014-11-19T13:26:23.114Z"),
    "chatlog" : "empty",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

please help me solve this error

Thank you

Comment: In the `findOne` call, should `staus` be `status` instead?

Comment: sorry typing error. but still it dose not work even if i try with 1 field

Comment: Can you edit your question to fix that and then add an example document from that collection that you expect the query to find?

Comment: Both of those docs have a `status` of 1, so they shouldn't be found. If you execute the query in the mongo shell does it return any docs?

Comment: lets say I use only totalmember: 1 but still i dont get any response. My browser window just keeps on loading... but let me try and then i will update my code

Comment: It looks like there's a syntax error in your routes.js. You close off the findOne, and the function is just sitting there, not in an exec() call, or as the last param in the findOne call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a syntax error because you **don't** pass the callback. Should be:

```
tblchatrooms.findOne({totalmember: 1, status: 1}, function(err, c) {
```

Instead of

```
tblchatrooms.findOne({totalmember: 1, status: 1}), function(err, c) {
```